# how to make text automatically go to the next line in bootstrap column

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have this row and column inside container

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" >
            <h1>About</h1>
<p>asdasdsadasdasdassdasdasdadassssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</p>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i make it go to the next line when it reach the end of the column?
[image: Layout]

Comment: A picture might be helpful here.

Comment: i posted a picture that might help

Comment: Put a space between words :) I mean, this is a fictitious case and there's no language where such a long word exists, even in german and finnish. Though URLs can be extra long

Answer (score 11):

Use `word-wrap: break-word`

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.break-text p {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="container break-text">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <h1>About</h1>
      <p>asdasdsadasdasdassdasdasdadassssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</p>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there no other way to make it more simple? like using bootstrap class?

Comment: @Otachan I don't think that there is any class in Bootstrap for this, you have to custom style it.

Comment: If you don't want the wrapping to be situational, you can simply add `word-wrap: break-word;` to the `p` tag in your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Just add to your CSS

```
.word-wrap{word-wrap: break-word;}
```

Then to your paragraph add the class

```
 <p class="word-wrap">asdasdsadasdasdassdasdasdadassssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</p>
```

Another option is to apply it to the whole site or all paragraphs, for example:

```
body {word-wrap: break-word;}
OR
p{word-wrap: break-word;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add style to table cell

```
td
 { 
    white-space: initial;
 }
```